# Can't create new Task

Tags: validation-rule, tasks, linkedin

I'm running into the error "Required fields are missing: [Status]" when trying to create a new Task, but `Status` is a PickList with a default value, so I don't why it won't use the default.  I believe this started happening after I installed the LinkedIn Sales Navigator app, which I know adds some task types, but I don't know how that could affect this.

Any advice on why it would say a field with a default is missing?

Comment: verify the running user has FLS viz to the `Task.Status` field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I have finally fixed this.  The issue was that when I installed the Sales Navigator plugin, I hadn't already had a Task type, so it defaulted to the LinkedIn task.  I was able to fix it by following the instructions under "KEY CALLOUTS" [here](https://business.linkedin.com/content/dam/me/business/en-us/sales-solutions/learning-center/customerhub/LISalesNavigatorForLightningSalesforceInstallationGuide_11-2-18.pdf):

> Note: Installation of Sales Navigator will create new Record Types for Tasks and assign custom defaults. If you do not have “Task” Record Types created, this can cause Record Types for Global Actions (e.g. New Event, Log a Call, New Task, etc.) to default to "--Master--" which would remove existing Global Actions from the Activities list.
>
> If after enablement you find that Global Actions are missing, please take the following steps:
>
> To Start this process, navigate to Objects and Fields in the Setup menu using “Quick Find”.
>
> Next, click Object Manager followed by Task. From here, click on Record Types followed by “New” in top right corner.
> Create a new Record Type labeled “Generic Task” or desired custom name. Make it Active
> and Enable for desired profiles.
> Next, from the Setup menu “Quick Find”, navigate to User Interface and then click Global
> Actions.
>
> Click “Edit” for each of the missing Global Actions, then click on the Record Type drop down
> menu. Select the custom Generic Task you previously created and then Save

Answer (score 1):

Default Values only apply to the UI. For any sort of automation, the Status field must be explicitly specified. You'll need to configure the app/code to supply a status value.